# Doctrine can't insert DateTime into MSSQL 2005

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, datetime, doctrine

I am using Doctrine 2.0 with php5.3 , being served from apache2 with a MSSQL\SQLEXPRESS 2005 backend.
   My problem is that when I go to insert a record with a DateTime object, I get the error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

As part of troubleshooting, I have verified that the target column is in fact of the type datetime. And I have echoed the query using the EchoLogger which returns something like this

```
INSERT INTO proposal (proposaldate, ...)
   VALUES (?..) { [1]=> object(DateTime)#264 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2010-11-20 22:15:12" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" }..}
```

The most disconcerting thing is that a similar class using the same packages executes flawlessly when inserting the datetime in the same manner.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2: Can't update DateTime column on SQL Server 2008apm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528444/doctrine-2-cant-update-datetime-column-on-sql-server-2008apm/54839504#54839504)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a locale issue. To overcome, write your strings out in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, ie. YYYYMMDD

```
2010/21/11
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I thought the PDO would handle the date formatting.  As in, it is passed a datetime object, and the PDO formats it by doing something like this.  $dateTime->format("ISO8601").  I have tried passing it a string, but it complains about not being able to call "format" on a non-object.

Comment: Turns out my column was labeled "datetime" as opposed to "date"