# Doctrine 2: Can't update DateTime column on SQL Server 2008apm

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, datetime, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2.2 with php 5.3 on an apache server.

So far I've stumbled upon the following problem:
When I try to update a datetime column I get:
SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I've even gone so far to make a get onto the column and then use that with only 1 day added to it to set the new date......same result.

When I instead change both the column in the database and in the entity from datetime to date, it functions as intended.

My main problem is, that there are a few fields where I will NEED to use a datetime column.

Here's my code:

(birthdate was the column I changed to date....and is one of the few columns where that is possible for me):

```
//This returns the datetime object that represents birthdate from the database 
$help=$object->getBirthDate(); 
$help->setTimestamp(mktime($time[0],$time[1],$time[2],$date[2],$date[1],$date[0])); 
$help->format(\DateTime::ISO8601); 
$object->setBirthDate($help);
```

Does someone know a workaround here?

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this problem with Doctrine 2.5 and SQL Server 2012. The problem is that the database field is type `DATETIME`, but doctirne only supports `DATETIME2` on SQLServer2008Platform and up.

You should not be editing files in your vendor directory. The correct answer is to create a custom type: [Doctrine Custom Mapping Types](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types). In my case, I extended the current DateTimeType:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Doctrine\Type;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class DateTime extends DateTimeType
{
    private $dateTimeFormatString = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.000';

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value !== null)
            ? $value->format($this->dateTimeFormatString) : null;
    }

}
```

And then in the Symfony config.yml:

```
    types:
      datetime: AppBundle\Doctrine\Type\DateTime
```

Comment: To apply this class outside symfony (if using `doctrine-orm` directly), just add `use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type; Type::overrideType(Type::DATETIME, 'YourNameSpace\DateTimeTypeSqlServer2012');` anywhere in your code before using any criteria with dates. I added it in the function that generated the EntityManager class, so that it's kind of a permanent fix.

Comment: For anyone now familiar with the doctrine YAML config in config.yml, the types: key should be added to the doctrine: dbal: key.

Answer (score 7):

Its an official bug in Doctrine 2.2, to be resolved in 2.3.

Microseconds are being casted to string with wrong amount of zeros.

Workaround:
Change function convertToDatabaseValue in File 
/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php:

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
   if( $value === null)
      return null;

   $value = $value->format($platform->getDateTimeFormatString());

   if( strlen($value) == 26 &&
         $platform->getDateTimeFormatString() == 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u' &&
         ($platform instanceof \Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SQLServer2008Platform
          ||
         $platform instanceof \Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SQLServer2005Platform
         ) )
      $value = substr($value, 0, \strlen($value)-3);
   return $value;
}
```

Comment: Over 3 years later now, the DBAL is at 2.5 ... and still no fix :( I also had to do workarounds like this in Doctrine 1.x when using SQL Server. Hello? High-quality libs like this will not earn credibility in the enterprise unless these things are ironed out. Sorry to rant, but I'm one of those who try to push for OSS in a largely M$ shop. Issues like this do NOT help my case.

Comment: How can I avoid changing files that are under Composer? How can I register my own type?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me fix this bug in one of our old projects.

Comment: @DinoAmino I don't know if this helps you at this point, but see my answer on how to fix this problem with DBAL 2.5

Answer (score 1):

I still had the same issue with Microsoft SQL Server Express 17 and Doctrine ORM v2.6.3/DBAL v2.9.2. (for Doctrine Platform, I use `SQLServer2012Platform`).

All you need to do is to change your SQL fields from `DATETIME` to `DATETIME2` type (wherever possible)

Answer (score 0):

What value are you passsing to the `datetime` field? You should pass a `Datetime` instance

```
$entity->setDate(new \Datetime());
```

Comment: Yes I'm passing a datetime instance. What I do is as follows (birthdate was the column I changed to date....and is one of the few columns where that is possible for me):

$help=$object->getBirthDate();  //This returns the datetime object that represents birthdate from the database

$help->setTimestamp(mktime($time[0],$time[1],$time[2],$date[2],$date[1],$date[0]));

$help->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);

$object->setBirthDate($help);