# Setting Date Field In Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I am having an issue setting a date type field in doctrine2. The underlying database is mysql. I am passing the setter a DateTime object but still get the following error: "Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object"

The code where I am attempting to set the value is as follows:

```
$date= new \DateTime('2016-08-12');
$deposit = new Deposits();
$deposit->setDepositDate($date);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($deposit);
$em->flush();
```

I have checked and confirmed that $date is a valid DateTime object so I am pretty confident that is not the issue.

The entity classifications for this field are as follows:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="deposit_date", type="date", nullable=false)
 */
private $depositDate;

/**
 * Set depositDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $depositDate
 *
 * @return Deposits
 */
public function setDepositDate($depositDate)
{
    $this->depositDate = $depositDate;

    return $this;
}
```

The error is being thrown within the **convertToDatabaseValue()** function in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php. I found a response to a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617999/6112068) which suggested that there was previously a bug with the way microseconds were cast which caused convertToDatabaseValue() to throw an error. However, the suggested fix did not work for me.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does the return $this do in your setter?

Comment: @LBA. It is standard ...

Comment: @LBA it's the so called 'Fluent Interface' - it helps making the code shorter if you use multiple setters on the same object.